# Copying specific styles from one element to another

Tags: jquery, css, styles, copy, inline

I have this code that would copy the contents of one element and place it on another. But I would actually like to copy the **inline style**, especially the positioning. Is there a way to copy the position style only, so that the info window will appear exactly where the `a.star` is when I hover?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.star').hover(function(){
    var instrument = '.instrument_info#' + $(this).attr('instrument');
    var htmlCode = $(instrument).html();
    $('.instrument_output .instrument_detail').html(htmlCode);
    $('.instrument_output').slideToggle();
  })
});
```

I want to get the inline positioning of this: `<div class="instrument_info" id="drums" style="top:95px; left:294px">` and put it in another div. How can I insert this in my jQuery code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.html()` doesn't include inline styles at all. You need to use the jQuery [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function;

```
$(".target_elements").css({top: $("someElement").offset().top, left: $("someElement").offset().left});
```

And since `.offset()` returns a `{top: ..., left: ...}` object, you can write the above more compactly as:

```
$(".target_elements").css($("someElement").offset());
```

Comment: +1 just as a side-note you can also do this :) `$(".target_elements").css($("someElement").offset());`

Comment: @pebbl Surely -- thanks for pointing that out! I'll edit it in.

Comment: One more thing can I get both the html attr and the css tags in just one function...

Comment: @tea_clipper Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Yes thanks @Abody97...the jquery code up there is working in getting the information that I want but I couldn't get my head around on how put the code ".css" inside the function coz if i do the whole jquery won't work..I hope I explain it right...

Comment: @tea_clipper I think you need to add the `.css()` extract just before the `.html()` part in your function.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to read those properties from one DOM element and assign them to another.

```
 var foo_offset = $('#foo').offset() # returns {left: 100, top: 100}
 $('#bar').offset(foo_offset)        # #bar's offset set to #foo's
```

Check out the [CSS documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/css/). All of the methods are designed with a signature that provides you the actual value of the property when called and assign objects to those properties if called with an additional argument.